# Adding higher resolution images to mosaic dataset

Tags: mosaic-dataset

I have a mosaic dataset to which I first added srtm data of 30 m of spatial resolution. Later on, I added another elevation dataset  (using table type, i.e., from another mosaic dataset) of 30 cm of spatial resolution overlapping the srtm dataset. I noticed that the 30 cm dataset is resampled and displayed at 30 m resolution. Is this normal? How can I make the mosaic dataset to display the original 30 cm dataset? I attach a screenshot.

[image]